# KeyError python dictionary trying to set new value

Tags: python, json

I have a json file of players and I want to update their stats, but for some reason this raises an error

Here's my code:

```
players = _load('players.json') #this is a load function I use

players[user]['coins'] = 1
```

And here is the error:

```
File "main.py", line 56, in index
    players[user]['coins'] = 1
KeyError: 'player1'
```

I've used this method of updating stats for a while now, doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Very hard to help you without an idea of the starting dict, or the expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The key error is being thrown since the `players` dict does not have a key in it for the variable `user`.

Check that `user` exists in `players` prior to doing the call:

```
players = {}
user = 'player1'

if user not in players:
    players[user] = {}

players[user]['coins'] = 1
```

Comment: Or use the `.setdefault()` method

Comment: Already checked in the original script, that's just a portion of it. doing players[user] = {} works great, thanks.